# Dynamically hide null rows in a Tableau crosstab with multiple parameters

Tags: salesforce, hierarchical-data, tableau-desktop

I have a Salesforce Campaign hierarchy dataset. The dataset has a parent-child structure. Overall there are 5 levels. Each level can have multiple campaigns. I have parameters set up to allow the user to select which combination of levels they want to see dynamically. The default hierarchal order is:

- Campaign Level 0 - overarching campaign
- Campaign Level 1 - parent
- Campaign Level 2 - child campaign
- Campaign Level 3 - sub child campaign
- Campaign Level 4 - grandchild campaign

I have 5 identical parameters with each option, then made a calculated field corresponding to each (another 5 identical fields). The calculated fields are then the rows

Not all Campaign hierarchies have every level, so there will be null rows. Is there a way to dynamically hide rows when I have multiple parameters already in place?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBIJ6.png)

This [article](https://www.rigordatasolutions.com/post/dynamic-hide-show-of-null-value-columns-in-tableau)  seems to meet my needs where you can sheet swap in a dashboard view and set up a parameter to dynamically hide based on what's selected in the filter. But I have multiple parameters that are set up as filters for one sheet.